# Django ORM Group By through two fields and sum result into third

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a `Move` model and those [objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu3Ay.png)

```
#python
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Move(modesl.Model):
    shipment_from = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        verbose_name=_("From"),
    )
    shipment_to = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        verbose_name=_("To"),
    )
```

And I can group by `shipment_from` and group by `shipment_to`. [Result of two queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADlae.png)

The question is: how do I achieve this result where `total` summarize for `place` with the same title?

```
# json
[
   {
      "place":"A",
      "total":3
   },
   {
      "place":"B",
      "total":3
   },
   {
      "place":"C",
      "total":2
   },
   {
      "place":"D",
      "total":4
   },
   {
      "place":"E",
      "total":2
   },
   {
      "place":"G",
      "total":1
   }
]
```